# Composition of monotonic functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(0) = 0, \, f(x) $ be differentiable and monotone increasing on $[0, +\infty)$. Prove:

$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}\, \text{ is increasing on (0, $+\infty$)}$$

$\vdots $

Counterexample:

Let $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$, then

$$f(0) = 0,$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \geq 0, \, \forall x\geq 0$$
$$g(x) = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} $$
$g'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0 \implies g(x)$ is monotone decreasing for all $x>0$. This problem is practice problem for an exam. I can't tell if it's written wrong, or if it's a trick question, or if I'm just not seeing it correctly.

Comment: You're right as far as I can tell. Seems patently false as written.

Comment: The question as written represents a false proposition. Perhaps you book meant "$f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,\infty)$". The proposition would then be true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$g'(x)=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^{2}}=\frac {f'(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{x}=\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}$

Comment: I see your logic, and it looks correct. But then why is my counter example false?

Comment: Actually your logic is not correct. $f'(x)$ isn't necessarily greater than $f'(0)$. So the answer depends on whether the differentiable function is convex.

Comment: Your last equality is invalid. You can't replace the difference quotient with derivative $f'(0)$ as they may not be equal. - 1 Moreover since the claim in question is false, this hint can't work.